# BasicDBObject or QueryBuilder and some newbie questions of Java and mongo

Tags: java, perl, mongodb, dbobject

hi I'm a fresh newbie to mongodb

Q1 
using

`query=new BasicDBObject();`

`query.put("i", new BasicDBObject("$gt",13));`

and

`query=new QueryBuilder().put("i").Greaterthan(13).get()`

is there any difference inside of the system?

Q2
I've created a class

```
class findkv extends BasicDBObject {    
    //is gt gte lt lte  
    public findkv (String fieldname, String op,Object tvalue)
    {
        if (op == "")
            this.put(fieldname, tvalue);
        else 
            this.put(fieldname, new BasicDBObject(op,tvalue));
    }
}
```

shall I use it or shall I just use original function?

Q3
I've used mongo shell for a few weeks, and was customed to it, and find writing in mongo shell faster and shorter, which side has more advantage, writing in mongo or in java?

I shall dump them from mongo to mysql

Q4

I've an `if (statement==true) return else dowhat;` seems can't be compiled
I know I can write if (statement!=true) dowhat else return, but can I still write in first style?

q5
my eclipse is 
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Juno Release
Build id: 20120614-1722
I'd like to install Perl which I haven't learned yet
I choose Install Update http://e-p-i-c.sf.net/updates/testing but it doesn't work, any method to install perl to eclipse manually?

Comment: Can I suggest you split this into 5 separate questions?  You have a greater chance of getting at least some of them answered that way.

Answer (score 0):

About your Q4-

Yes you can do that by any of these 2 ways.

```
if (statement==true) 
   return ;
else 
   dowhat ;
```

Or

```
if (statement!=true)
   dowhat ;
else 
   return ;
```